# Java sort strings in codepoint (UTF-32) order

Tags: java, unicode, compare

Other than to convert to UTF-8 bytes, or write a compare function that iterates and compares, is there some method I'm missing in JDK 1.6 that compares two strings in full Unicode codepoint order instead of in UCS-2 codepoint order?

I appreciate that this is not a hard thing to code. I was puzzled, however, that 1.6 has the various 'codepoint' APIs in `java.lang.String` as well as the Collation system, but apparently nothing to simply compare two strings without hiccuping on the surrogates.

For the benefit of a commenter, I have to feed some data to a tool that wants the strings in this order.

Comment: It already does that by default? Or do you *actually* want to take account with diacritics in the ordering? E.g. `aa`, `aà`, `ab` instead of (default) `aa`, `ab`, `aà`? Otherwise I don't see any reason for this question :)

Comment: String.compareTo is at least in Sun's JVM 1.6.0_16 implemented as a comparison of the contained chars. This will not work with bmargulies requirement if the string contains surrogate pairs for characters outside the BMP.

Comment: Actually, this behaviour is described in the API documentation, so it's not an implementation detail of Sun's VM to base compareTo on the char values.

Comment: Is there now a solution for this in the current Java 1.8/1.9 API?  Or maybe within a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIk, the API has no such method, but it should be trivial to implement it yourself. Just out of curiosity: What do you need something like that for?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness her my solution to the problem. Maybe there is a better solution:

```
   String sortedText = text
      .codePoints()
      .sorted()
      .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i)))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```